# Grails GORM hasMany association inconsistent with MongoDB, When try to fetch child Records,it fetches the record sometimes and doesn't fetch sometimes

Tags: mongodb, hibernate, grails, grails-orm

Below is the domain class `Author` which has a one-to-many association with `Book`. When trying to fetch Author, sometimes will get the associated collection of `Book` domain object and sometimes returns null. Any thoughts on why it is inconsistent?

`class Author {
    static mapWith = "mongo"
    String name
    static hasMany = [books: Book]
}`

_author.gson

`model {
    Author author
}`


`json g.render(author]) {
    books g.render(author.books)
}`

Environment details:

`grailsVersion=3.3.5
gormVersion=6.1.8.RELEASE`

We are using GORM multi-tenancy and using MongoDB database.

Comment: Shot in the dark, what happens when you add List<Book> books = new ArrayList(); in your domain class Author?

Comment: @JasonHeithoff 

Not sure, if ```List<Book> books = new ArrayList()``` will save ```books``` data.

```static hasMany = [books: Book]``` and ```List<Book> books = new ArrayList()``` are same only.

Let me try your solution as well. I'll update here once I am done with testing it.

Comment: @JasonHeithoff I have tried your solution but no luck.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have switched to sub-document model and it's working now. Here is the domain model code.

```
class Author {
    static mapWith = "mongo"
    String name
    List<Books> book
    static embedded = ['book'] 
}
```